# What does delete[] do if given a pointer to the middle of an array?

Tags: c++

What would happen in the following code?

```
    int *p1 = new int[100];
    int *p2 = &p1[50];
    delete [] p2;
```

I've heard that some implementations of new store the size of the array in the (-1)th array index, but then wouldn't things go horribly wrong in the above?

Comment: This duplicate was quite easy to find... it would be great if you could do some research before posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

Things would definitely go wrong!

The **delete []** operator is defined to only work on *proper* array pointers. And by proper I mean it must receive a pointer that was previously initialized to point to a location in memory where an array was created with the **new** operator.

You should also never mix and match new/delete and malloc/free. As a rule always *delete* memory that has been allocated with `new`, and *free* memory that has been allocated with `malloc` (and derivatives)